# Como realizar duas seleções distintas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Boa tarde pessoal,
estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo onde o usuário terá uma quantidade de números, por exemplo de 01 a 20 e ele deverá realizar duas seleções, 3 números vermelhos e 5 azuis.
A primeira seleção ele marcará os números de vermelho e a segunda seleção marcará os números de azul. Ele só pode iniciar ou continuar a seleção de números em azul após todos os números em vermelho estiverem selecionados.
Então, supondo que ele seleciona os 3 números de vermelho, e depois selecione 2 em azul e após ele desmarque um número vermelho, o próximo número que ele marcar deverá ficar em vermelho para então ele continuar com os números azuis.

Ao selecionar a opção Randômico, ele seleciona automaticamente 3 vermelhos e 5 azuis.

Segue código.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

input[type=checkbox] {
  display:none;
}

.default 
{
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.azulMarcado
{
  color: white;
  background-color:#4682B4;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.vermelhoMarcado
{
    color: white;
    background-color:red;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="resultado">
<label id="div_input_1" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="01" id="input_1"/>01</label>
<label id="div_input_2" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="02" id="input_2"/>02</label>
<label id="div_input_3" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="03" id="input_3"/>03</label>
<label id="div_input_4" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="04" id="input_4"/>04</label>
<label id="div_input_5" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="05" id="input_5"/>05</label>
<label id="div_input_6" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="06" id="input_6"/>06</label>
<label id="div_input_7" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="07" id="input_7"/>07</label>
<label id="div_input_8" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="08" id="input_8"/>08</label>
<label id="div_input_9" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="09" id="input_9"/>09</label>
<label id="div_input_10" class="default"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this)" value="10" id="input_10"/>10</label>

<div>
  <br>
  <button type="button" name="random" id="random" onclick="random()">
   Aleatórios
  </button>
</div>

<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

<script>
var globalAzul = 0;
var globalVermelho = 0;

function add(_this)
{
    var objeto = _this.id;
    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    var value = objeto.value;
    var hasAdd = resultado.value.search(value) > 0; 

    if(_this.checked && !hasAdd)
    {
        resultado.value += ' '+_this.value;
    }
    else if(!_this.checked && hasAdd)
    {
        var er = new RegExp(_this.value, 'ig');
        resultado.value = resultado.value.replace(er, '');
    }     

    resultado.value = resultado.value.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');

    var totalAzul = 3;
    var totalVermelho = 2;
    var objetoDivClasse = document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className;

    if (!document.getElementById(objeto).checked)
    {
        if (objetoDivClasse.indexOf("azul") != -1)
            globalAzul = globalAzul - 1;
        else if (objetoDivClasse.indexOf("vermelho") != -1)
            globalVermelho = globalVermelho - 1;

        document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className = "default";
    }
    else
    {
        if (globalAzul >= totalAzul && globalVermelho >= totalVermelho)
        {
            document.getElementById(objeto).checked = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (globalVermelho < totalVermelho)
            {
                document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className = "vermelhoMarcado";
                globalVermelho = globalVermelho + 1;
            }            
            else if (globalAzul < totalAzul)
            {
                document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className = "azulMarcado";
                globalAzul = globalAzul + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("labelTotalAzul").innerHTML = globalAzul;
    document.getElementById("labelTotalVermelho").innerHTML = globalVermelho;
}

function random(){

  //Armazeno as suas opções
  var nodeList = document.getElementsByName('campo');

  //limpo o resultado
  //document.getElementById('resultado').value = '';

  //Percorro suas opções 
  for(i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++){

    //Desmarco todos
    nodeList[i].checked = false;
  }

  var i = 0;
  while(i<5){
    //Pego um indice aleatorio do array
     var indiceAleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random() * nodeList.length)

    var option = nodeList[indiceAleatoria];

    //Se a opção ainda não foi sorteada adiciono ela.
    if(option.checked == false){

      //Marco a opção sorteada
      option.checked = true;

       //Adiciono a opção sorteada
       alert(option);
       add(option);

      i++;
    }
  }


}
</script>


<br>
Total Azul:<label id="labelTotalAzul">0</label><br>
Total Vermelho:<label id="labelTotalVermelho">0</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tive muito tempo pra pensar numa lógica boa, mas se for mais ou menos isso, você pode ir melhorando conforme precisa:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.azulMarcado
{
  color: white;
  background-color:#4682B4;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.vermelhoMarcado
{
    color: white;
    background-color:red;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div_input_1"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="01" id="input_1"/>01</div>
<div id="div_input_2"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="02" id="input_2"/>02</div>
<div id="div_input_3"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="03" id="input_3"/>03</div>
<div id="div_input_4"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="04" id="input_4"/>04</div>
<div id="div_input_5"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="05" id="input_5"/>05</div>
<div id="div_input_6"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="06" id="input_6"/>06</div>
<div id="div_input_7"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="07" id="input_7"/>07</div>
<div id="div_input_8"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="08" id="input_8"/>08</div>
<div id="div_input_9"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="09" id="input_9"/>09</div>
<div id="div_input_10"><input type='checkbox' name='campo' onclick="add(this.id)" value="10" id="input_10"/>10</div>


<script>
var globalAzul = 0;
var globalVermelho = 0;

function add(objeto)
{
    var totalAzul = 5;
    var totalVermelho = 3;
    var objetoDivClasse = document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className;

    if (!document.getElementById(objeto).checked)
    {
        if (objetoDivClasse.indexOf("azul") != -1)
            globalAzul = globalAzul - 1;
        else if (objetoDivClasse.indexOf("vermelho") != -1)
            globalVermelho = globalVermelho - 1;

        document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className = "";
    }
    else
    {
        if (globalAzul >= totalAzul && globalVermelho >= totalVermelho)
        {
            document.getElementById(objeto).checked = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (globalAzul < totalAzul)
            {
                document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className = "azulMarcado";
                globalAzul = globalAzul + 1;
            }
            else if (globalVermelho < totalVermelho)
            {
                document.getElementById("div_" + objeto).className = "vermelhoMarcado";
                globalVermelho = globalVermelho + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("labelTotalAzul").innerHTML = globalAzul;
    document.getElementById("labelTotalVermelho").innerHTML = globalVermelho;
}
</script>


<br>
Total Azul:<label id="labelTotalAzul">0</label><br>
Total Vermelho:<label id="labelTotalVermelho">0</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Andreia, me ajudou muito já. Só tenho mais uma dúvida. Como eu recebo os checkbox separado por cor?

Comment: @Tadeu eu não entendi sua duvida

Comment: Preciso apresentar os números selecionados, porém, divididos pelas cores.

Comment: Supondo que você selecione dois números vermelhos e depois dois azuis, depois você tire um número vermelho e adicione novamente, e depois adicione outro azul. A variável que armazena os valores do checkbox mistura tudo. Eu preciso que sempre fique armazenado primeiro os números vermelhos, seguidos dos números azuis.

Comment: Atualizei o código da postagem para você ver como ficou. Falta acertar apenas essa questão de armazenas os valores separados pela cor.

Comment: você fala no textbox? porque no label está separando

Comment: Sim, no textbox que está sendo apresentado o resultado. Se você selecionar certinho na ordem, fica certo, porém, se você desmarcar um vermelho no final por exemplo e remarcar, ai a ordem já fica bagunçada.

Comment: pega então o text do item removido e da um replace por ""